# Can you test android apps on cyanogenmod?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I have a Nexus 5 and want to begin making apps in the future, but I personally want to use CM instead of the stock OS.

Can you test android apps on CM and is it representative of how apps would behave on the stock OS?

Comment: You may refer this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922971/is-it-reliable-to-test-an-android-application-on-a-rooted-phone-with-cyanogenmod/18925973#18925973

Comment: Yes. You can do a test.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can test apps on Cyanogenmod.

Remember that Android is an open source system and that Cyanogenmod is possible because of the fact that Android is open source.  If you look at Smart phone makers like Oppo are actually using Cyanogenmod in their phones.

Android APK's can be tested on pretty much any device that is capable of running that APK.

For example if you make an android Game that supports lots of devices then yes but if you make a highly demanding game that supports only high end devices then you can only test on those high end devices.

http://www.techlivewire.com/tag/android